# Detect if OS is available (e.g. std::mutex)

Tags: c++, macros

Is there a way to detect via macros if the target platform supports std::mutex?

I would like to contribute to an open source project we us, because they are using std::mutex. We are using gcc-arm-none-eabi, where std::mutex is not available (but RTOS specific mutexes).

If I could detect via a preprocessor macro if no OS is available, I would enable (ifdef) code to provide a custom mutex.

I could test for gcc-arm-none-eabi but since there are also other "bare-metal" compiler out there, I would rather like to test the absence of a feature instead of the presence of a compiler/target platform.

Comment: Something like these...? https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros

Comment: @Eljay yes, but there isn't a feature testing macro for this particular case.

Comment: By "std::mutex is not available" you mean the whole header `<mutex>` would be unavailable, the class `std::mutex` is not defined or it is there, but you are not allowed to use it?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen std::mutex  not defined. Header is always there. the ifdef inside <mutex> are not portable.

Answer (score 2):

The standards do specify a few predefined macros that can potentially help.

Firstly, `<mutex>` was introduced in C++11, so we can use the predefined macro `__cplusplus` to detect if our implementation claims to be C++11 or later.

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
```

Second, the C++11 standard specified that a hosted implementation is one for which a program can have more than one thread executing concurrently (as distinct from a standalone implementation, where ability to have more than one thread executing concurrently is implementation defined).   Conveniently, it also introduced a predefined macro `__STDC_HOSTED__` to test for a hosted implementation, and an optionally defined macro `__STDCPP_THREADS__` to test if a program can have more than one thread of execution.   Both expand to `1` if true.

```
#if __STDC_HOSTED__ == 1 && __STDCPP_THREADS__ == 1
```

In most cases it would be reasonable to assume that a system that cannot have more than one thread of execution would not support means of synchronising between them.

Putting all that together, we get (using the fact that an undefined macro will not test as equal to `1`)

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L && __STDC_HOSTED__ == 1 && __STDCPP_THREADS__ == 1

#include <mutex>

//   code that uses <mutex> here


#else

// start testing for other OS and mutex/thread mechanisms here
#endif
```

I have not tested the above, but this is what I would use as a first cut before starting to dig into testing macros that are specific to particular host systems or compilers.

Comment: This is how it should work but the reality is different. Even Clang and GCC are not defining `__STDCPP_THREADS__ ` at all (on linux).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a small c++ source file that uses `std::mutex`. If the compilation fails, you may assume you don't have `std::mutex`.

How to do this during project  build and set a preprocessor macro depends on your build system.

Comment: Thank you but this is to complicated for open source projects I don't own and are for example header only.

Comment: @Viatorus Then you need to use whatever macro and document that it needs to be defined for such platforms so whoever uses that library puts that into their build system.